# Is this a serious paint defect?

Tags: frames, paint

I am about to receive a bike and the shop has informed me of the following (cosmetic, they claim) paint defect:
[image]

Since I don't have a lot of experience, is this something that might chip off? Or is just an accumulation of paint? Shall I be concerned?

Comment: What's the frame material?

Comment: I'm impressed you even noticed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like excess paint and I personally wouldn't call 7x2 millimeters a *serious* defect, especially if it is the only defect. It is in an area that's hardly ever visible when you ride your bike, an imperfection on the top tube would be far more notable because you look down on it all the time.

It is also in an area that might receive damage (chips, scratches) from taking out the wheel frequently, at least that happens to me with QR axles, I have no experience with thru-axles.

I personally wouldn't mind, but poor paint quality might become a functional issue when there is paint overspray in areas that should be properly masked while painting the bike: on the inside of the headtube or bottom bracket holes where bearings or BB shells go - also on disc brake caliper mounts. Sloppy paint might lead to an imperfect fit of bearings or even the rotors scrubbing and should be sanded off by a careful bike mechanic.

However, if you think this isn't acceptable for you and your LBS offers a free swap with acceptable timelines, why not go for the better bike?